# Volume of a revolution

Tags: calculus

If the area between the curve $y=\ln x$, the $x$-axis, and the ordinate $x=3$ is rotated $180^\circ$, find the volume generated.

I tried $\int_0^3 \pi(\ln x)^2dx$, but it appears to be wrong. Can somebody please help?

Comment: Edited. Now with LaTeX!

Comment: If it's 180 degrees, isn't that only a half-turn? The cross-sections are semicircles, I think.

Comment: Yeah,its a hemisphere but not necessarily circular. In fact, its tree shaped.

Comment: OH, I think I got it wrong because I forgot to subtract the negative portion of the Lnx graph.

Comment: Let me quickly check my calculations. Nope, still doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need to find your bounds correctly.

The function $y = \ln(x)$ crosses the $x$-axis at $1$, not $0$.  As $x \to 0$, $\ln(x)$ approaches $-\infty$.

Then, your cross sections are semicircles, each with area $\pi/2 \cdot [\ln(x)]^2.$

Then, your integral becomes:

$$V = \int_1^3 \frac{\pi [\ln(x)]^2}{2} dx.$$

Can you take it from there?

**EDIT:**  OK, this caught me off guard possibly, as the integral on $[0,1]$ is finite.

What about this?

$$V = \frac{\pi}{2} \left[\int_0^1 [\ln(x)]^2 dx + \int_1^3 [\ln(x)]^2 dx \right] = \frac{\pi}{2}\left[6 + 3 [\ln(3)]^2 - 3 \ln(9)\right]$$

The shape is a bit odd, but it does have a finite volume.  You'd need to add the two areas, since they both sweep out positive volumes.

**RE-EDIT:**  The $y$ axis isn't mentioned as a boundary, so it does stop at $x=1$.

$$V = \frac{\pi}{2} \left[\int_1^3 [\ln(x)]^2 dx \right] = \frac{\pi}{2}\left[4 + 3 [\ln(3)]^2 - 3 \ln(9)\right].$$

Hopefully this is my final answer.  O_o

Comment: wouldn't you need to add that to the integral with bounds 1,0 to take into account the negative LN part. I tried that but the answers are wrong >.<

Comment: @Tomato721 [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kZvoi.jpg) is a graph of the x-axis, the line x=3, and the curve $y=\ln x$. I shaded in the region between the three.

Comment: @columbus8myhw He does have somewhat of a point, possibly regarding the bounds.  The value of $\ln(x)$ blows up at $0$, but the integral from $0$ to $1$ doesn't.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @John The question specifically says it's between the three. (There are clear rules on what's "between" a curve and a horizontal or vertical line.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw Ooooohhh, you're right!  It didn't mention the $y$ axis, did it?  Yeah, that's not a boundary.  O_o

Comment: Happens to the best of us. By the way, @Tomato721, as for actually _evaluating_ the integral, I believe you need Integration-by-Parts.